# Version history of items in related list

Tags: list, version-history

Is there a way, without additional programming, to get history of children related items to the parent one, for example:

```
SPList threads = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Blog threads"];
SPList posts = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Blog posts"];
```

posts have lookup field - threads, of course.
Looking into the selected thread history I wish to know when a post was added it it, when was deleted or which changed.

I know I can iterate throug all items related:

```
SPList posts = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Blog posts"];
        SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
        spQuery.Query =
            "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Thread' LookupId='true' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + threadId +
            "</Value></Eq></Where>";

        SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = posts.GetItems(spQuery);

        foreach (SPListItem spListItem in listItemCollection)
        {
            string historyUrl = "/_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={" + posts.ID + "}&ID=" + spListItem.ID";
            ...
        }
```

But I won't have info about deleted, changed items.

To summarize: I need a history of an item with all realated child items from other lists. (SharePoint 2010 if it matters)

Answer (score 1):

If you have versioning enabled on the list you can access the versions of a SPListItem by the [SPListItem.Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx) property.

You could also use event receivers ([SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx)) to track the changes and store the changes in another list.

Comment: Yes I know I can use EventReceivers and insert info to the third list, but as I've mentioned, I'm looking for a solution that will work for current items as well.